# angular-route : Is it possible to have a route param in the base url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Is it possible to have a route param in the base url with ngRoute?

```
 <base href="/some/resource/path/:myParameter/" />
```

together with:

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/third', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'someController'
    })
    .when('/forth', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'someController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/first'
    });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

to get routes of:

```
/some/resource/path/:myParameter/first
/some/resource/path/:myParameter/second
/some/resource/path/:myParameter/third
/some/resource/path/:myParameter/forth
```

Comment: No, because router's mission is change url state. `base` tag cannot make a change urlstate

Comment: I would recommend switching to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) because it allows states inheritance (which will be usfull in this case) and much more